# Azure Enterprise State Roaming page load error

Tags: azure

I am looking into enabling Azure State Roaming on a test group, the user in the group has Azure P1 so I am assuming that is all that is required to get it working.

When I first clicked the tab and entered the group that seemed to work but now when I go to the State Roaming option I get an error that says:

> An error occurred while loading this page. You may not have permissions to view this data.

Not sure why I would get this as I am a Global Admin so I should have the permissions and it was working earlier today.

When I try and go to a device to see what is being synced it does say that I have to enable to option but I am unable to get to the option because of the above error.

Can anyone think of why this could be?

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for the trouble.  There was a backend issue with Enterprise State Roaming blade earlier which prevented users to access the blade.  This issue is resolved now and I am able to see the blade without any issues.
[image]
Can you please check and confirm now if are able to access it.